# Prove $(X,d)$ is a metric. Where d is the number of entries a vector is not equal.

Tags: analysis, metric-spaces

I am reading through my applied analysis book and trying to prove all of the things that have not been proven in order to prepare for an exam. Here is one of the examples: 
Let $X$ be the set of $n-$letter words in a $k-$character alphabet $A = \{a_1,\ldots ,a_k\}$ meaning that $X = \{(x_1,\ldots,x_n)|x_i\in A\}$. Define the distance between two words $x = (x_1,\ldots,x_n)$ and $y = (y_1,\dots,y_n)$ to be the number of places in which the words have different letters. That is $$d(x,y) = \#\{i|x_i\neq y_i\}.$$

Then $(X,d)$ is a metric.

My question is how to show that satisfies the triangle inequality mathematically.

$Let x = (x_1,\ldots,x_n), y = (y_1,\ldots, y_n) and z = (z_1,\ldots,z_n)$. Suppose $x$ differs from $z$ in $m\leq n$ positions, $y$ differs from $z$ in $i\leq n$ positions and $x$ differs from $y$ in $j \leq n$ positions. Then 
$$d(x,y) \leq j$$ and $$d(y,z)\leq i.$$ The maximum number of positions $x$ and $y$ can be different are $n$ and similarly for $y$ and $z$. Therefore we have 
$$ n+n = 2n \geq n \geq m .$$ This is what I have so far but I know there is more to it. Thank your for any help and comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nice one.

The idea is that if, lets say, $x_1 \neq z_1$ then we cannot have $x_1 = y_1$ and $y_1 = z_1$. So whenever $d(x,z)$ goes up so does $d(x,y) + d(y,z)$. Can you take it from here? Though that essentially proves it.

Just googled around and it's called the [Hamming Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance).